# How do i get the name of a service from the proccess id?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-services

I got the process id of the running service using the code below as well as the process name, but i all i really want is the service name/key.Is there a way to get that from either the process id or the process name? Using c++

```
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
unsigned int i;

if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
{
    return 1;
}


// Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.

cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

// Print the name and process identifier for each process.

for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
{
    if( aProcesses[i] != 0 )
    {
        PrintProcessNameAndID( aProcesses[i] );
    }

}
```

and..

```
void tt_coreutils_ns::PrintProcessNameAndID( DWORD processID )
{
 TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");

// Get a handle to the process.

HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
    PROCESS_VM_READ,
    FALSE, processID );

// Get the process name.

if (NULL != hProcess )
{
    HMODULE hMod;
    DWORD cbNeeded;

    if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), 
        &cbNeeded) )
    {
        GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, 
            sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
    }
}

// Print the process name and identifier.

_tprintf( TEXT("%s  (PID: %u)\n"), szProcessName, processID );

// Release the handle to the process.

CloseHandle( hProcess );
```

}

updated code

```
    DWORD pId=GetCurrentProcessId();
SC_HANDLE hSCM    = NULL;
PUCHAR  pBuf    = NULL;
ULONG  dwBufSize   = 0x00;
ULONG  dwBufNeed   = 0x00;
ULONG  dwNumberOfService = 0x00;


LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS pInfo = NULL;

hSCM = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);

if (hSCM == NULL)
{
    printf_s("OpenSCManager fail \n");
    return 0xffff0001;
}

EnumServicesStatusEx(
    hSCM,
    SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO,
    SERVICE_WIN32, // SERVICE_DRIVER
    SERVICE_STATE_ALL,
    NULL,
    dwBufSize,
    &dwBufNeed,
    &dwNumberOfService,
    NULL,
    NULL);

if (dwBufNeed < 0x01)
{
    printf_s("EnumServicesStatusEx fail ?? \n");
    return 0xffff0002;
}

dwBufSize = dwBufNeed + 0x10;
pBuf  = (PUCHAR) malloc(dwBufSize);

EnumServicesStatusEx(
    hSCM,
    SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO,
    SERVICE_WIN32,  // SERVICE_DRIVER,
    SERVICE_ACTIVE,  //SERVICE_STATE_ALL,
    pBuf,
    dwBufSize,
    &dwBufNeed,
    &dwNumberOfService,
    NULL,
    NULL);

pInfo = (LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS)pBuf;
for (ULONG i=0;i<dwNumberOfService;i++)
{
    cout<<"display name "<<pInfo[i].lpDisplayName<<"\t service name: ";
    cout<< pInfo[i].lpServiceName<<"\tid: "<<pInfo[i].ServiceStatusProcess.dwProcessId<<endl<<endl;

    if(pId==pInfo[i].ServiceStatusProcess.dwProcessId)
    {
        cout<<pInfo->lpServiceName;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the service name? The name in `services.msc` or the name of executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerate all the services using [EnumServicesStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (pass `SERVICE_WIN32` as a service type). In the output, you'll get `ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS` structs that contain service name and another `SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS` struct, which has `DWORD dwProcessId` field.

This way you can map process id to a service name/key.

Comment: i tried this, i updated my original post with my code using this, but it never seems to match the process id to the the process id from EnumServicesSatusEx as it never goes into my if check and never displays the service name

Comment: @Bullsfan127 your code prints-out correct PIDs. Do you see your service in the task manager? Does its PID (or at least name) appear during the enumeration?

Comment: The process Id displays correctly and matches up with the id in my task manager, but when it is retrieving all the process id's and displaying them all of the service names and id's display correctly except for the process i am using which displays as 0 as if it were inactive.